# Fail to make Regex for .net select substring after #

Tags: c#, .net, regex

From a string like this

> some description 123 #code123

I need just this:

> code123

The idea is to split string after # character. I tried these regex patterns:

> (?:#)(?<=.*?)     ->it's give me just "#" 
>
>   (.*?#)(?<=.*?)     ->it's give me "some description 123 #" 
>
>   (?:.*#)(?<=.*?)    ->it's give me "some description 123 #"

Comment: You may use `(?<=#).+` or `#(.+)` (and grab `match.Groups[1].Value`, group 1 value). Could you please explain why you must use a regex here? Do you have access to the code?

Comment: If you just need everything after the first # why not use `string.IndexOf` and `string.Substring`?

Comment: Or string.split("#")[1]

Comment: Is what comes after # what you're trying to split, example "forget this, but #`split` `words` `here` `and` `here`" ? If it's this, it can easily be done in a single regex match.

Comment: I can't use any code, unfortunately - this is intended to be mask for a field used in one of our ERP systems.

Comment: Do you want the match to find all text before the `#` and after, or **only** match what is after the `#`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the regex option `RightToLeft` to work from the end and get all characters except the `#`:

```
string input = "some description 123 #code123";

Regex.Match(input, "[^#]+", RegexOptions.RightToLeft)
```

Returns in match groups 0 value:

```
code123
```

---

Otherwise if you can't use that option, then use what is called a positive *look behind* of `(?<= )` which tells regex to parse the string until it finds a specific text to *come behind* what will be matched. That anchor type text you seek is `#` hence this pattern of the look behind and the matching text is:

```
(?<=#)(.+)
```

Which says look for a `#`, that is not consumed (*matched*) and the following characters, one to many will be **matched** resulting in:

```
code123
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply - 
I can't use any code, unfortunately - this is intended to be mask for a field used in one of our ERP systems. I tried to use [^#]+   - I got both "some description 123" and separate "code123" splitted at #